# Used space displayed for my Google disk is 4 times more than total size of the stored files

Tags: google-workspace

As it follows from the notification displayed, I have used almost all available Google disk space (96%) while the total size of the files are 3.5 Gb only. Additional 1Gb was deleted and stored in the bin. What is the reason an how can I fix it? Also I have a lot of files shared with me from other accounts. But regarding Google Disk documentation they should not be taken into account. Additionally I have 0.8GB in Gmail and no files in Google photo

Comment: Are you using Google Drive? Your question seems not to be related to GCP. In addition, do not spam tags. Datastore is a noSQL DB and it is not related to any kind of disk

Comment: Unfortunately there is no Google Drive tag available, so I was trying to find something related to Google technologies and most close to my question.

Comment: "Unfortunately there is no Google Drive tag available" That's because Stack Overflow is for questions about *writing code*, not about using someone else's software. Please try https://superuser.com. While we do offer some support for e.g. IDEs, or using the command line to run one's own code, nothing about the question here suggests anything to do with programming.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to this [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/quota) and evaluate what are the files that are consuming more storage
2. Delete the files in your [bin](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/trash), as they are still counting towards your quota
3. After you delete the files, it usually takes some time to update the space on your Drive. A propagation matter.
4. Make sure you don't have a lot of [photos](https://photos.google.com/u/1/quotamanagement) taking quota out of your account